# Starting session on jquery mobile, without ajax

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-mobile

Here's my problem, I'm using Jquery mobile for the first time ( student web developer) to make an web app. So I need to do a login page , and then start a session. But I don't know how to do it. Does it work only using PHP session ( because I know how to do it with Php only.. ) ? Or do I really need to do it an other way?
This is how I did it:

```
<?php
include 'fonctions.php';
    if (isset($_POST['valider'])){

    if ((isset($_POST['ident']) && !empty($_POST['ident']))  
    && (isset($_POST['psw']) && !empty($_POST['psw']))) {

        // récupération des infos de connex
        $identifiant=$_POST['ident'];
        $psw=$_POST['psw'];

      if(connectionIdent($identifiant,$psw) ===true){
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['id'] = $identifiant;
          $_SESSION['psw'] = hash("sha256",$psw);
          header ('Refresh:0; URL= http://localhost/acces.php#radio');

      }else{
          Echo 'Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrects';
          header ('Refresh :3; URL=http://localhost/acces.php#connexion');
      }
    }
    }
?>
```

And my landing page:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['psw'])){
        echo 'Votre login est '.$_SESSION['login'].' et votre mot de passe est '.$_SESSION['pwd'].'.';
    ?>

   <div data-role="page" id="radioSansCo">

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

          <div data-role="panel" class="sidenav" id="mypanel" data-display="overlay" data-position="left" >
                <a href="#" class="buttonnav" id="liennav">Forum</a>
                <a href="#" class="buttonnav" id="liennav">Bon plans</a>
                <a href="#" class="buttonnav" id="liennav">Actualités</a>
                <a href="#" class="buttonnav" id="liennav">Deconnexion</a>
            </div>
          <a href="#mypanel"><span  id="sandwich">&#9776;</span> </a>

            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logocentral">

        </div>

    </div>
   <?php 
  } 
   ?>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "session" in JS. But you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store some data on client-side. **Do not use it to store user password** since this would not be secure. Your PHP way, as you posted it, is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php needs you to start the session. Some people do custom token/database solutions, but for simplicity I just stick to the php sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();//don't forget to start the session on the php side.
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['psw'])){
        echo 'Votre login est '.$_SESSION['login'].' et votre mot de passe est '.$_SESSION['pwd'].'.';
?>
```

Comment: Whoops. Missed it. Thanks. It won't help on the second page because each page has to start the session.

Comment: That is true! I missed it on the second page... We're even ;)